# Tab widgets in QGIS plugin - run different scripts

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3

Is it possible to run separate python processes through tab widgets of the same QGIS plugin. I have created a QGIS plugin using the plugin builder. From QT designer I added two tab widgets to the plugin. I want to run different processes in both the tabs, one at a time though. Right now I can run the process in the first Tab, but I do not know how to add the script to the second tab and run it when the 'OK' button in second tab is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define separate class methods in your main plugin class and connect them to different buttons in your UI tabs. For example, if you have buttons with object names like `ok_btn_1` and `ok_btn_2`, in the `initGui` method of your main plugin file, connect the clicked signal to the methods which contain the 'processes' you want to run.

```
def initGui(self):
    ...
    self.dlg.ok_btn_1.clicked.connect(self.process_1)
    self.dlg.ok_btn_2.clicked.connect(self.process_2)
```

then make sure you have defined those class methods:

```
def process_1(self):
    # Do something

def process_2(self):
    # Do something else
```

I have just created a GitHub repository with an example of a simple plugin with a tabbed UI (created without PluginBuilder or QtDesigner). Hopefully you may find it useful:

https://github.com/benwirf/QGIS_Example_Plugins/tree/master/test_plugin

Comment: Thanks, I understood up till here and even managed to have tow tab widgets in the plugin (I used the QGIS plugin builder). In the second widget I added a push button and could run the process, but how to add one button to close the plugin interface, like the default 'QDialogButtonBox' that comes from QGIS plugin builder?

Comment: No worries @Dew_ale. The method to close the whole dialog will be `self.dlg.close()`. Now that you understand a little about event handling, you should be able to work out how to add a button to your main dialog, (not in the tab widgets) and connect it to a function which implements that method. Hint: for a one line function, it often makes sense to pass a lambda function e.g. something 
like  `self.dlg.btn_close.clicked.connect(lambda: self.dlg.close())`.